# Error - "There is no script engine for file extension .vbs" when using "Git Bash Here" in Windows 7

Tags: git, vbscript

I have the latest release version of git for windows installed. When I use the context menu option *Git Bash Here*, I get the following error.

> There is no script engine for file extension .vbs

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The problem is caused by associating `.vbs` files with a program other than `Microsoft Windows Based Script Host` (the default). In my case, I had associated the files with Notepad++. I was able to solve it by running Notepad++ as an administrator and removing the file association for `.vbs` files.

If you're not sure which program is causing the problem, you can find out by searching for "Change the file type associated with a file extension" from the start menu. To fix the problem from there, make sure that .vbs files have `Microsoft Windows Based Script Host` set as the current default program.

Comment: For those who are less familiar with Notepad++, where do you set file associations?

Comment: Instructions for Notepad ++ ver. 7.3.3 (may be different for really old versions): If you have multi-instance enabled, you may need to close all but one instance of Notepad++. Go to **Settings** -> **Preferences**, and click on **File Association** from the list on the left. Then from the _Registered extensions_ list on the right, select **.vbs** (may have to scroll down), and click on the left arrow ( **<-** ) to remove it from that list.

Comment: I've changed the default program for .vbs files but it doesn't solved alone. Wasn't fixed until I remove .vbs from Notepad++ associated files.

Answer (score 42):

In my case I was able to get out of this rid by re-associating the vbs files with the following command: cmd-->Run as Administrator --> now type the following command and press enter

> assoc .vbs=VBSFile

Comment: This was the only way I could do it. Thanks :)

Comment: While trying your solution getting 'Access denied, error occurred while processing .vbs' . what to do?

Comment: @BhartiMohane: As mentioned in the solution, have you run your cmd -->Run as Administrator ?

Answer (score 6):

You can try executing the appropriate fix from the link below.

http://www.dougknox.com/xp/file_assoc.htm

Comment: Thanks, this was the only fix that worked for me on Win 7 64-bit!

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 6):

I've had this problem when trying to use NVM for switching node versions on Windows 10 64bit Pro. The only solution that worked for me was to fix registry entries. I'm not an expert on how registry entries may affect your system so **use this at your own risk**.

**Step 1**: Create a vbsfix.reg file

**Step 2**: Open it in notepad (or some other text editor)

**Step 3**: Copy paste the following code:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbs]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbs]
@="VBSFile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbs\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile]
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,77,00,73,00,68,00,65,00,78,00,74,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,\
  00,2d,00,34,00,38,00,30,00,32,00,00,00
@="VBScript Script File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,57,00,53,00,\
  63,00,72,00,69,00,70,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\ScriptEngine]
@="VBScript"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\ScriptHostEncode]
@="{85131631-480C-11D2-B1F9-00C04F86C324}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell]
@="Open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Edit]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Edit\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,25,\
  00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,57,00,\
  53,00,63,00,72,00,69,00,70,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,\
  00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,25,00,2a,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open2]
@=hex(2):4f,00,70,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,26,00,77,00,69,00,74,00,68,00,20,00,43,\
  00,6f,00,6d,00,6d,00,61,00,6e,00,64,00,20,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,6d,00,70,00,\
  74,00,00,00
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,77,00,73,00,68,00,65,00,78,00,74,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,\
  34,00,35,00,31,00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open2\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,43,00,\
  53,00,63,00,72,00,69,00,70,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,\
  00,25,00,31,00,22,00,20,00,25,00,2a,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Print]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Print\Command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,2f,\
  00,70,00,20,00,25,00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\ShellEx\DropHandler]
@="{60254CA5-953B-11CF-8C96-00AA00B8708C}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers\WSHProps]
@="{60254CA5-953B-11CF-8C96-00AA00B8708C}"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.vbs]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.vbs]
```

**Step 4**: Save it and Run it as admin.

If you find an issue with this please let me know.

Comment: Although it seems a bit dodgy meddling with registry entries, this is the only solution that worked for me :)

Comment: I thought so too when I first came across this solution. Still can’t confirm what it actually does but it did work for me.

Comment: It worked, you are a genius!

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that associating Notepad++ with .VBS files will cause this issue.

For Windows 10, if you navigate to "Choose default apps by file type", you will be unable to re-associate .vbs with the "Microsoft Windows Based Script Host"; that interface will basically state the same / original problem - no application installed for the file type.

[image]

The CMD line solution from khichar.anil, above, works flawlessly with Windows 10.  Be sure to run as an Administrator.

[image]

The GUI will take a moment to update thereafter:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I tried the above methods, none of them worked for me on Windows 10. I ended up going to the Windows Registry and change the Default value for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.vbs to VBSFile and only then it worked.

Comment: Can you add some more detail to this answer and possibly a screenshot?  This is ultimately what worked for me, but there was a subfolder to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.vbs` entry in the registry editor so I was unsure whether to set the top level or the child item (it ended up being the parent)

Comment: @GrantHumphries Sorry this was exactly 2 years ago, my memory is erased over and over since then! :)

Answer (score 3):

Although this is a dead post, I wanted to share this with others that come along.

I had the same issue as the OP, but the .vbs files were already associated with "Microsoft Console Based Script Host".

This was happening on a Windows Server 2012 machine, and the .vbs file was being called by a .bat file.

The solution for me was to run `cscript.exe /H:CScript`, or alternatively run `cscript.exe /H:WScript`. This associated a script engine for this script to use.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using WEBuilder.
To solve it, I went in the Options/Preferences/Files/Associations
and removed the association with .vbs files.
Cheers!