# “Can’t Find Script Engine Vbscript” Or “There Is No Script Engine for .Vbs”

Tags: java, email, vbscript

I am using a VBScript file named `BrowserError.vbs` which is accepting one argument from the Java class am using. The vbs file is used send an email when there is a test case failure with a screenshot.

**Problem:**

If I run the vbs file from command prompt it works fine and sends the email with attachment.

But if I run from the Java class it gives the following error:

> No Script engine for .vbs TL02_Validate_ChaterInvalidLogin-1-11Apr16_045433

`BrowserError.vbs`:

```vb
Dim ToAddress
Dim MessageSubject
Dim MessageBody
Dim MessageAttachment
Dim name
Dim folder
Dim displayMsg

Dim ol, ns, newMail

name = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
FromAddress = "abc@def.com"
ToAddress = "abc@def.com"
CcAddress = "abc@def.com"
MessageSubject = "Sanity Error Alert !!!"
Set ol = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ns = ol.getNamespace("MAPI")
Set newMail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
MessageAttachment = "C:\Users\****\Desktop\********\CnetWorkSpaceBranch\SanityBranch\target\surefire-reports\html\screenshots\" & name & ".png"
Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(MessageAttachment, 1)
strFileText = "Hi, Error notification on Sanity- User has encountered problem  : Refer screenshot "
objFileToRead.Close
Set objFileToRead = Nothing
newMail.Subject = MessageSubject & Now
newMail.HTMLBody  = strFileText
newMail.To = ToAddress
newMail.CC = CcAddress
newMail.Display
newMail.Attachments.Add(MessageAttachment).Displayname = "Check this out"
newMail.Send
Set ol = Nothing
```

The Java code which is used to pass the argument is like this:

```java
String tnm="TL02_Validate_ChaterInvalidLogin-1-11Apr16_045433";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C:/BrowserError.vbs"+tnm);
```

My core interest is to just send the email and get the value from the Java class while running and sending the email.

Comment: In Java, it appears to a vbs programmer, that there should be a space after `.vbs`. The error message says it is trying to execute a script with an extension of `vbsTL02_Validate_ChaterInvalidLogin-1-11Apr16_045433` of which there isn't one.

Comment: See this [Stackoverflow Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757248/error-there-is-no-script-engine-for-file-extension-vbs-when-using-git-bash) and perhaps [this](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/error-there-is-no-script-engine-for-file-extension-when-running-vbs-files/).  My advice (and Stackoverflow rules) is that you google the error message before posting. Otherwise things get cluttered with redundent low nurishment posts. If my pointers do not help let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Noodles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6017774/noodles) pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550571/can-t-find-script-engine-vbscript-or-there-is-no-script-engine-for-vbs#comment60702635_36550571) to your question, you're appending the argument directly to the script path, thus creating an unrecognized extension.

Change this:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C:/BrowserError.vbs"+tnm);
```

into this:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C:/BrowserError.vbs "+tnm);
//                                                    ^
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: i added a space in between  .vbs and the arg[0].  now it is working fine.   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C:/BrowserError1.vbs"+" "+referScreenshot+" "+test_case_name);